# Onclick in body change div position with javascript coordinates

Tags: javascript

i just want to change div position onclick, when i click in the body i want div to appear there.

```
#elem{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;

}
```

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elem");
elem.onclick = funct;


function funct( event ){

     var x = event.clientX;
     var y = event.clientY;
        this.style.top = y + 'px';
        this.style.left = x + 'px';
}
```

Comment: You have not stated a question, nor a problem. But if by _"Onclick in body"_ you mean you want the click event to happen anywhere in the body and not only on the element than put the listener on the body and not on the element.

Comment: well with your code, it will move when you click on the element.... So seems like you are binding the click to the wrong place.

Comment: i know but i can not get click on the body) so that's why i let the click in the element

Comment: Did you try to add a click hander on the body or window or document? If you did, show us what did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working example. You need to add event listener to document/body element:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   target.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
   target.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
});
```

```css
#target {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

You can expand the handler further and center the div on the cursor position as well:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   target.style.left = e.clientX - target.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
   target.style.top = e.clientY - target.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
});
```

```css
#target {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: No problem. :) I've added another example as well. :)

Comment: Thank you) i just did not understand how to get body click by right way

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to mark the correct answer. :)